# how to check if a number is a BigInt in javascript

Tags: javascript, bigint

i want to check if a number is a BigInt in a acceptable size if statement

i know there is the solution

```js
function isBigInt(x) {
    try {
        return BigInt(x) === x; // dont use == because 7 == 7n but 7 !== 7n
    } catch(error) {
        return false; // conversion to BigInt failed, surely it is not a BigInt
    }
}
```

but i wanted to implement the test directly in my if statement, not in my function

can someone help me with that?

Comment: You can insert a function call inside of an if statement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof). If the number is a BigInt, the `typeof` would be "bigint". Otherwise, it will be "number"

```js
var numbers = [7, BigInt(7), "seven"];
numbers.forEach(num => {
  if (typeof num === "bigint") {
    console.log("It's a BigInt!");
  } else if (typeof num === "number") {
    console.log("It's a number!");
  } else {
    console.log("It's not a number or a BigInt!");
  }
});
```

Comment: A bigint can also be [wrapped into an Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt). In this case `typeof num === 'object'`

Comment: @Serge in that case, (value).constructor === BigInt should work.

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operator can help you if I understood your question well:

```
...
const isTernary = BigInt(x) === x ? true : false
...
```

you will have in your variable "isTernay" either true or false depending on whether your number is a bigint or not.

And a BigInt object is not strictly equal to Number but can be in the sense of weak equality.

```
0n === 0
// ↪ false

0n == 0
// ↪ true
```

Visit : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt for more about BigInt

Comment: You don't even need the ternary in boolean situations (i.e. where you write `cond ? true : false`), it's enough to write `cond`. The problem is with the `try..catch`, which can't be inlined.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would simply be (assuming you only work with numbers):

```
Number.prototype.bigInt = false
BigInt.prototype.bigInt = true
```

And then you could simply call `myNum.bigInt` to check.

NOTE: `3.bigInt` will not work because `3.` is considered a number, so you could do:

```
(3).bigInt
 3 .bigInt
```

or use it on a variable

Answer (score 0):

Quick suggestion:

```
if (BigInt(n) === n.valueOf()) {
  // is BigInt
} else {
  // not a BigInt
}
```

Handles both literal BigInt such as `123n`, and an Object-wrapped one: `Object(123n)`.  [Both forms are valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#type_information) BigInts with different `typeof` results: "bigint" vs an "object".

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested to see if the value is a native BigInt, I think @Rojo's suggestion to use

typeof value === 'bigint'

is the best.

But if the BigInt is provided by a custom class (a 'polyfill') then the typeof expression will evaluate to `'object'`.

But the following does work:

```
value.constructor === BigInt
```

(Note: `value instanceof BigInt` does not work for the native BigInt type)